# override manager approval in infopath form

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise

I have an infopath form on sharepoint 2013. The form needs to be approved by a manager who is on leave. What can i do to set the approval or override the approval to make the form workflow continue?

Answer (score 0):

Is the form workflow a SharePoint Designer 2010 platform workflow?

If Yes, Please make sure the setting is unchecked for the approval action:

[image]

Then sign in your site using a site collection administrator and approve the task.

have a try and let's know the result.